# How to change Laravel 5.2 change login route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello I am using Laravel 5.2 version. I installed the laravel project via composer. After that I use command **"php artisan make:auth"** for create auth. After created auth route is generated for example **"http://localhost:8000/login"**. Now I don't want this route I want to set different route for example **"http://localhost:8000/super/admin"**. So How can I change the **"http://localhost:8000/login"** to **"http://localhost:8000/super/admin"**. And when auth generated that time **/register**  route is create so that route i want to remove **"http://localhost:8000/register"** route. Please suggest me how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these simple steps

If you have `Route::auth()` in your `routes.php`, then please remove that line.

Now add the following lines to your `routes.php`

```
Route::get('super/admin', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin')->name('auth.login.get');
Route::post('super/admin', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin')->name('auth.login.post');
Route::get('super/admin/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout')->name('auth.logout.get');
```

Then go to `login.blade.php` (most probably in **resources->views->auth**)

And change the form action to `{{ route('auth.login.post') }}`, like this...

```
<form action="{{ route('auth.login.post') }}" method="post">
```

Hope this answers everything :)

Comment: if i remove Route::auth() in my routes.php so all controller my auth is working or not. After remove Route::auth() I have to create custom auth for my project?

Comment: @dhanashri I added the logout Route as well. And no, you don't have to use custom Auth... The AuthController made after entering `php artisan make:auth` is being used here.... Nothing is required from your end now. Everything should work as expected... And the register link will also not work :)

Comment: @dhanashri Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: in a newer Laravel version it was renamed to Auth::routes()

Answer (score 1):

In `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`
 - define a fuction named showLoginForm() as:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
        ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';

    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

It overrides the function showLoginForm defined in the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.`

Note: In Laravel 5.3 the function name is changed from getLogin to  showLoginForm. 
**For details goto** 
`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.`

Answer (score 1):

In the routes file, instead of using the default `Route::auth()`, you have to register the routes yourself.

My advice would be to run `php artisan route:list`. This will show you the default routes and their respective controllers (and methods). Then, remove `Route::auth()` and implement the routes you want manually.

So for example, if you want to change to login URL, you'd have to define it as:
`Route::get('super/admin', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');`

Do this for all the routes you want to replace. By removing `Route::auth()`, you're removing the register route.

Comment: if I remove Route::auth() then all project I have to create custom auth?

Comment: No, just reference the existing controllers. For example all `Route::auth()` does is declare `Route::get('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');` for you. By removing it and explicitly